# Regular Expression, Summing

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm working on a problem to sum all numbers in a text file. I've solved it, but I know I can consolidate the code more.

```
x = re.findall('[0-9]+',opened.read())
x = [int(i) for i in x]
print sum(x)
```

I want to do something like this, but I just don't know:

```
print sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+',opened.read())])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do python people want everything on one line? It doesn't improve readability or efficiency (in most cases). Like they say, if it ain't broken, don't fix it.

Comment: @cricket_007 Trying to learn all that I can!

Answer (score 1):

You're mostly there. You can drop the brackets (to `sum` a generator expression without the intermediate `list`), and you could use `map` (ideally Py3 `map` to avoid the intermediate `list`) for brevity/performance (only a perf gain because `int` is a built-in implemented in C; normally `map` is slower):

```
# genexpr
print sum(int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\d+', opened.read()))
# Or with finditer to avoid intermediate list
print sum(int(m.group()) for m in re.finditer(r'\d+', opened.read()))

# map
from future_builtins import map  # Only on Py2

print sum(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', opened.read())))
```